# making a field of quotients from a specific ring question

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R=\{ i+j \sqrt3 \space \space | \space i,j \in \mathbb {Z} \}$
So im asked in a an exercise to show that this is a ring with the usual operations addition and multiplication im also asked to find all the units of the rings.

it turns out if $ gcd(i,j)=1 $ then it is not a unit additionally it turns out that an element is a unit iff $i^2-3j^2 =\pm 1 $

Now my question is the following.

Let Q be its field of quotients.

Prove that if $ [a,b]$ is in Q then there exists $c \in R$ and $k \in \mathbb {Z}$ and  $ k \neq 0 $ s.t $[a,b] = [c,k]$

i think what this is asking about is the fact that in the rationals $\frac {3}{6} = \frac {1}{2} $ I believe its asking me to find two unique elements in my Ring that land in the same equivalence class. The problem im having is that im not really sure im understanding how there making the equivalences classes from the elements in my Ring they dont look like the example i have from the integers.

Comment: What is $[a,b]$? Why don't you just use $Q=\{r+s\sqrt{3}\mid r,s \in \mathbb{Q}\}$?

Comment: For some reason im my course its defined to be the Equivalence class of $\frac {a}{b} $

Comment: They define two elements in a quotient group to be (a,b) its rather confusing to be honest.

Comment: For the quotient field of $R$ you can just transfer the equivalence classes to the classes of $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., using rational coefficients.

Comment: I think $ Q= \{ r+s \sqrt 3 \space | \space r,s \in \mathbb {Q} \} $ is what my Q is supposed to be but how do i know that it is?

Comment: i think im understanding finally ( sorry im kind of slow with this stuff) do i need just one case where this is true to complete the proof or do i need to show for any equivalence class theirs at least 2 things in it? i mean if i assume j=0 then for i=1 and k=1 and i=2 and k=2 they both belong to the same equivalence class. and they are clearly unique elements in my  Ring

Comment: @Faust7 Don't worry about uniqueness: the question does not ask for $k$ to be unique.  Just think of this as multiplying the numerator and denominator by *something* so that the denominator becomes an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more or less a straightforward unfolding of the definition.

Let $Q(R)$ be the field of quotients for $R$. Let's recall that the elements of $Q(R)$ are the equivalence classes of pairs $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in R$ and $b\neq 0$, under the equivalence relation

$$(a,b) \sim (c,d) \iff ad = bc.$$

Basically what you are asked to show is that the equivalence class of $(a,b)$ contains a representative of the form $(c,k)$, where $k$ is an integer. Concretely, given $(a,b)$, you must show that there exists $c\in R$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$$ak = bc.$$
Can you think of a way to pick $c$ so that $bc$ is an integer multiple of $a$? I'll let you try your hand at finding the appropriate $c$ and $k$, but you could always ask if you need some additional hints.

Note that the idea here is to show that you are allowed to pick a particularly simple form for the representative of your fraction. Namely, this result states that every element of $Q(R)$ has a representative of the form
$$\frac{c}{k} = r+s\sqrt{3},$$
where $r,s\in\mathbb{Q}$. This shows that you may identify $Q(R)$ with the field
$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})=\{r+s\sqrt{3}\mid r,s\in\mathbb{Q}\},$$
as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Nitpick: The analogy with reducing a fraction to lowest terms is a bit misleading since in this problem the denominator has no uniqueness requirement and in fact has infinitely many choices (in a sense it is completely orthogonal to the concept of reduction to lowest terms).  The OP seems to have some confusion regarding uniqueness, but I can't quite make sense of it.

Comment: @ErickWong Fair enough, it _is_ a bit misleading. I shall remove the part regarding the analogy.

Comment: Im alittle confused i want to say that c=a but that just reduces to me saying k=b as well which just feels like im saying what im trying to prove...

Comment: @Faust7 You can't choose $c=a$ in general. You must show that there exists a $c$ for which $ak = cb$ is true, so you are not allowed to arbitrarily choose $c$ to be whatever you want. Your example precisely shows that choosing $c=a$ is not allowed here, unless $b$ were already an integer itself. As an additional hint, can you think of some element $b'$ such that $bb'$ is an integer?

Comment: well yeah if b is a number then $b * b^{-1}$  is always 1. but i dont understand why b isnt an integer, isn't the $[a,b]$ defined is such a way the b must be an integer?
Bezouts identity says ax+by=d is always possible feel like you want me to use that somehow

Comment: @Faust7 Well, here $b$ isn't a number, but rather an element of $R$. In particular, it may not be a unit. Nevertheless, there is always another element $b' \in R$ such that $bb' \in \mathbb{Z}$. There is nothing that says $b$ itself must be an integer. In fact, $a$ and $b$ here are completely arbitrary elements of $R$. Note that elements of $Q$ are _not_ pairs of numbers, but an entire equivalence class of such pairs. So you shouldn't think of the pair $(a,b)$, but the entire equivalence class it represents.

Comment: Sorry im just not understanding. when i think about this im seeing a as some element in my ring and b as some integer in Z. ive managed to glean that this is the wrong way to think about a field of quotients. is (a,b) the quotient  of some element a and b in my ring? if thats the case then i see no reason why $bb' \in Z$ i mean b could be a zebra then for all i know if is just the element of a ring?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of $R$. In particular, you should think of the integers as embedded in $R$ in the form $k + 0\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: I think im close to understanding the concept i really appreciate all the help but i have a midterm tomorrow and i dont think im going to figure this out in a reasonable amount of time so im just going to hope it doesn't come up and try and cover some other material. Thanks alot though.

Comment: @Faust7 No one is saying $bb'$ *has* to be in $\mathbb Z$.  It's up to you to *choose* $b' \in R$ so that $bb' \in \mathbb Z$.  As long as it works, you can choose any element except for $0$.  Given all that freedom, can you think of any good choices?

Comment: Im going to try n go with $c=b^{-1}a $ though i think someone said im not allowed to pick a. that would make $ ak= b b^{-1} a $

Comment: @Faust7 That would be the right idea _if_ $b$ were a unit. But $b$ isn't necessarily a unit, and $b^{-1}$ may not exist. However, there is something analogous even when $b$ isn't a unit. For example, think about the complex numbers. How do we define the norm of a complex number? Is there something similar here?

Comment: Welol the complex conjugate. We can multiply the expression $i+j3^{1/2}$ by $\frac  {i-j3^{1/2} }{i-j3^{1/2}}$ it will give of us something of the form c/integer ?

Comment: If we let c= the element $(a1+a2 \sqrt 3) (b1-b2 \sqrt 3)$ we get an expression for c as the product of two elements in R and it's forces k to be an integer for all elements a,b in Q. Thank you guys so much sorry it took me like 2 days to figure this one out. Accepting answer now.

Comment: @Faust7 Yes, I'm glad you got the answer. More precisely, every element $b\in R$ comes with a conjugate $\overline{b}$, obtained by automorphism $\sqrt{3}\mapsto -\sqrt{3}$. The product $b\overline{b}$ is precisely the norm $N(b)$ of $b$, where $N(b) \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus taking $c = a\overline{b}$, we get $cb = a\overline{b}b = aN(b)$, which is an integer multiple of $a$, as required. Note that you can show that $b$ will be a unit in $R$ if and only if $N(b)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., iff $N(b) = \pm 1$. This is precisely the condition $i^2 - 3j^2 = \pm 1$ you had in your question.